# Exporting Text in HTML Text Field

Tags: javascript, python, php, html, css

I am creating an HTML web application [application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TuA2.png) to predict stock prices. The user is to enter in a specific ticker (i.e. AAPL) into the text field. The user then hits the Go button. Upon hitting the Go button, I want to export whatever ticker the user entered in the text field into my Python machine learning model. How do I go about this? I am new to HTML so the simpler the solution is the better! Let me know if you have any questions.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Stock Prediction</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Stock Prediction</h1>
    <textarea placeholder="Enter ticker here..." id="text"></textarea>
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Go</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
#text {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #021652;
    border: 2px solid #3ba9f4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    resize: none;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

#submit {
  background-color: #3ba9f4;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 174px;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

I do not know where to start :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `<textarea>` and `<button>` into an HTML tag `<form>` and handle this form submit. Based on the nature of your application you can use either submit flow with full page reload like this:

`<form method="POST" action="/query">`
(this will do a POST HTTP request to `http://yourserver/query` and send a data from the `textarea` field).

Or you may want to handle form submit using JavaScript and do a XHR request to your server (which is a modern way used by the most of the sites for the last 10 years).

There is a snippet which should give you an idea how it works.

```js
document.getElementById('prediction-form').addEventListener('submit', handleForm)

function handleForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(document.getElementById('text').value)
  
  // add logic to send query to some backend here
}
```

```css
#text {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #021652;
    border: 2px solid #3ba9f4;
    border-radius: 2px;
    resize: none;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

#submit {
  background-color: #3ba9f4;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 174px;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>Stock Prediction</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Stock Prediction</h1>
    <form id="prediction-form">
        <textarea placeholder="Enter ticker here..." id="text"></textarea>
        <button id="submit" type="submit">Go</button>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I used vanilla JS (native browser API with no libraries), but you may want to use some library which provides an API to easily work with HTML DOM and events like [jquery](https://jquery.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Really helped. One more quick question, when I do the first method (form method="POST" action="/query"), I get an error saying the file cannot be accessed. Do I create a blank html file for this or how do I add the "query" file?

Comment: I assume that you have some HTTP server running on your local machine to serve pages and handle requests. It depends on your backend architecture and language. But basically you should have some apache/nginx service which gonna route requests to the dedicated files. Example: if you have php server and you send request to "/query" your apache should be configured to forward request to the file "query.php" and here you put a logic to handle those request.